# Trying to define selectedItem within IndexChangeEvent Flash Builder

Tags: syntax, drop-down-menu, flash-builder, selecteditem

I have this code as a change function on a DropDownList in Flash Builder:

```
public function chooseCategoryDDL_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {

    var para:Object = new Object();
    para.action = "changecategoryxml";
    para.book_class = event.selectedItem.book_class;

      if (event.selectedItem > -1 ) {
          changeCategory.send(para);
       }
```

However I get a code hint stating that there's 'access of undefined property selectedItem'. Yet when I set the para.book_class to be:

```
 para.book_class = event.IndexChangeEvent.book_class;
```

The code hinting then states error '1078: Label must be simple identifier'. What i'm trying to do is when a user clicks on a selected item from the DDL, the 'changecategoryxml' function is called if the selected item is > -1 (as the DDL is an ArrayCollection). Please can anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I now know how accept rates works, please don't be put off by the relatively low percentage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `event.currentTarget.selectedItem` with the IndexChangeEvent. That should work in your case as well.